# How to search an object in another object in angular 6,7,8

Tags: angular

When i was searching for an another object in one object i am not getting in search option.What have i written in my code html and ts file are

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="search-hero">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" 
         autocomplete="off" placeholder="&#61442;  Start searching for a hero by id or name or 
                                                                 country">
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>Id</th>
               <th>Hero Name</th>
               <th>Country</th>
               <th>venky</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes | filter:searchText">
             <td>{{hero.id}}</td>
             <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
             <td>{{hero.country}}</td>
             <span *ngFor="let ven of venky | filter:searchText">
             <td>{{ven.nam}}</td>
             </span>
           </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

and in ts is

```
export class AppComponent   {
title = 'Angular Search Using ng2-search-filter';
searchText;

venky = [
{ id: 1, nam: 'venky' },
{ id: 2, nam: 'neeru' }  ];
heroes = [
{ id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice', country: 'India',"nam":this.venky},
{ id: 12, name: 'Narco' , country: 'USA',"nam":this.venky},
    ];
}
```

when i have been searching for an object of venky in heroes but its not coming in search.Please anyone help here

Comment: What's the "filter" pipe? That's not an Angular thing, so must be some form of custom pipe?

Comment: ok, but what i need to take instead of that please explain?
thanks

Comment: I'm not here to write your code or your question for you. Please explain what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried so far, and what specific problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please read the

https://ciphertrick.com/search-sort-pagination-angular

here you got the example `ng2-search-filter`

you already added heroes `"nam":this.venky` so you can directly use it html so it filter pipe working.

```
 <span *ngFor="let ven of hero.nam">
```

Comment: Yeah thanks i referred but,in my code without venky object its been working fine,while invoking another object(venky) its not showing anything means getting empty.
thanks

Comment: games = [                                                                                                                    
    {                                                                                                                                 
      "id":"1",                                                                                                                     
      "name": "DOTA 2",
      "genre": "Strategy",
Cricket=[{
            "id":1,
            "name":"venky"}]
    },

Comment: if we take an object like Cricket in the above comment i am getting null
Thanks

Comment: why you add another array in HTML you already added `"nam":this.venky},` you can directly access that like   `<span *ngFor="let hero of venky.nam >`

Comment: Yeah, for one object its working but when i am trying to search object inside another object its not coming     Thanks

Comment: An object a list of data is there from that i am trying to get data by using array this.venky[0].nam

Comment: Yeah i got an idea from your answers Thanks for showing interest.Thanks @ Kurt Hamilton